# Necessary steps when referencing Javascript file in HTML (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a javascript file named text_messages.js

The file is already referenced it on my html.erb using 
`<%= javascript_include_tag "text_messages"%>`

and it is in the `config.assets.precompile`

when I insert the javascript directly in the html file using `<% content_for :javascript do %>
<script type="text/javascript">`  the code works perfectly fine. Confused as to how i should go about this. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I can quite understand the problem. Is the issue that your JavaScript code doesn't run?

Comment: @ClemensKofler the issue is that the html page doesn't seem to be using the javascript code. The program runs fine but the javascript functionality is not there at all.

Comment: Can you post the javascript?

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer https://pastebin.com/gbGTjgLT

Comment: @quincosa can you try wrapping the `//Initializing call` inside a ready var and call that on document.ready (or page:change / turbolinks:load as Clemens mentions) so you would have
 
`ready = function() {
    setTargettedContacts();
 
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        inline: true,
        sideBySide: true
    });
});

$(document).ready(ready);`

Comment: and is something popping up in the JS console? Sometimes having the wrong loading order (because javascript_include_tag works differently than content_for:) can throw your JS out of whack - If the ready trigger doesn't solve it I would try creating a simple JS file with a ready trigger that just console.logs something or alert();, and include that and see if it fires, if not there something wrong with your require's and the order you're loading them I guess? Maybe jQuery is coming to late?

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer Thanks for the response. I wrapped it in the ready var and it seems to be having the same issue. I believe my code is doing a good job referencing the html elements so I don't see why this issue is occurring. Going to try that out now!

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer I got it to print in the console when wrapped it in a ready var! but now the error in the console is such `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at text_messages.self-070645d….js?body=1:32` Once Again THANK YOU

Comment: quincosa I would say that all your //ACTIONS on the codepen ought to be inside the `ready` function, since you want to call those once the document is fully loaded and the DOM final (e.g. you want to bind the EventListeners and be sure that the elements to which you're binding them exist). Then the named functions you have can be outside the `ready` handler. Since those will be called on particular executions

Comment: Hey that worked perfectly! Some of my code is now buggy when i was working perfect before. Is there something i should be paying attention to when making this change from front end javascript to a javascript file? @MicaelNussbaumer

Comment: Bindings and "globalish" variables should go inside the ready handler, e.g.: `$(".btn").mouseup(function(){
    $(this).blur();
})` then besides that, pay attention to the scopes. Usually what I do is, I have a ready handler, with a few lines of code which are basically function calls and initial bindings. Functions are defined outside the ready handler and that's it, they're called when needed. You should also make sure that the code evaluates correctly on runtime - not like  functions that are defined on initialisation and keep outdated references throughout execution

Comment: Thank you @MicaelNussbaumer You solved my problem!!

Answer (score 0):

An issue that occurs regularly is that your app uses [Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic) but your JavaScript keeps using jQuery's `ready` event. This only works if the page your JS is running on happens to be the first page you're rendering in the browser.

You can check whether or not you're using turbolinks by looking at the `application.js` file: If it contains `//= require turbolinks` (or `#= require turbolinks` if you're using CoffeeScript), you know that you're using it and might be falling into this trap.

If this is the case, there are three options to solve the issue:

1) Replace all occurrences of the `ready` event with `page:change` (or `turbolinks:load` if you're using Turbolinks 5) which covers both page changes as well as the original `ready` event.

2) Use the [jquery-turbolinks gem](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks).

3) Remove turbolinks altogether.

Generally, I prefer option 1 since I don't like adding extra gems. The only downside is that you have to manually define some events if you're using JavaScript packages that define their own ready events – otherwise they won't be picked up properly.

Comment: Thanks @ClemensKofler thanks for the response. Here is what my application.js looks like... `//= require jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js
//= require pace/pace.min.js
//= require slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require_tree .`  I am not using Turbolinks. Thanks!!